# Sending a variable with AJAX to 2 php pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a question regarding sending variable thru AJAX to 2 outside php pages, So I have a variable in `fab.php` that will be used in `data2.php` and `data3.php`

So the ajax in `fab.php` is this

```
$(function(){
    // SHOW RECORD
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $.post('data2.php',
                            {action: "show", 
                             "hm":$('#headmark').val()},
                             function(res){
        $('#result').html(res);
        });     
    });
});
```

And I successfully able to use "hm" in `data2.php` with this

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'show'){


    $sql   = "SELECT * FROM SUB_MASTER_DRAWING
                     // "hm" is passed from the previous page
                      WHERE SUB_MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = '{$_POST["hm"]}'";
```

In this page the results corresponded with "hm" value should be shown and user can direcly update it and send the updated value back to the server in `data3.php`
In order to update it, I still need the "hm" value that is selected to make the update process in data3.php

I Tried this method but it doesnt work

```
 $(function(){
    // SHOW RECORD
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $.post('data2.php', 'data3.php',
                            {action: "show", 
                             "hm":$('#headmark').val()},
                             function(res){
        $('#result').html(res);
        });     
    });
});
```

Comment: send it to `ONE` and Use `SESSION` for many pages

Comment: hi samitha, 

im not sure on how to use session to pass variable.

Comment: I was post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Send your `$.ajax` request to `data2.php` use SESSION

**In data2.php**

```
     <?php
     session_start(); #start session here

   #declare session varible and assign POST value to session 
    $_SESSION['getvalue'] = $_POST['getValue'];
```

**In data3.php**

```
 <?php
  session_start(); #start session here

   #And use  $_SESSION['getvalue'] now
```

Comment: I already used session for the connection method in data2.php 

    require_once '../dbinfo.inc.php';
    session_start();

can i send another session instead ?

Comment: if you are already use `session_start()` now you only need  `$_SESSION['getvalue'] = $_POST['getValue'];`

Comment: if you are thinking this answer is useful.make it as the perfect answer